# How to setup owl carousal on Shopify venture theme?

Tags: shopify, owl-carousel, shopify-template

How to setup owl carousel on Shopify venture theme?
I need to add carousel slider to my Shopify theme? Can anyone help me how to do?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in order to improve your question please.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, here's everything that you need to add owl carousel: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-installation.html